# How to create an on-screen android keyboard that isnt a rectangle at the bottom portion of the screen?

Tags: android, keyboard, replace, shapes

I want to develop a replacement keyboard, but I am afraid that Android assumes the general keyboard 'area' will be a single rectangular shape that sits at the bottom of the screen.

What if I want my keyboard to consist of multiple shapes that don't just sit at the bottom of the screen?   Am I doomed from the start, or is it possible to do what I want to do?

On a related note, what if I only want my keyboard to appear when the phone is in a certain orientation but when the phone is held at a different orientation, the normal soft keyboard is used?  Again, out of luck or possible?

cheers!

Comment: I apologize if you really were "hot to create" a replacement Android keyboard. :)  Interesting question, by the way.

Comment: mwah ha ha, I am but Ill accept your edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IME is just a window.  It is positioned relative to the bottom of the screen, so you can't really control that.  But you can draw whatever you want in it, or not for places you want to be transparent.  You can control how much applications move up away from your IME with this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onComputeInsets(android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.Insets)

Android doesn't let windows decide one at a time whether events will be handled by them or dispatched to the window behind them; the only control you have to keep events from being consumed by your entire window is the Insets.touchableInsets constants to tell the window manager to allow events outside of the given insets to go through to what is behind it.

Comment: Hi, thanks Hackbod, thats what I was afraid of.  From my point of view at least, it would be great if I could create a keyboard window -- or for that matter floating window(s) for any kind of purpose -- that could appear on any side of the screen, and shrink the space available for the underlying Activity to the area they dont overwrite.

Comment: This is a long shot, but would it be possible to use a transparent fullscreen Activity as a fake IME?  It sends any characters typed in  to the Activity immediately below it?  Or can you think of any other way to hack what I want?

Comment: OK, I see the bit in your link about Fullscreen IME.  I suppose this would let me technically do what I want to do, without the underlying on-the-fly interaction with the underlying Activity.  That last part might be a deal breaker, its hard to say without trying it to see what its like.

Comment: The limitations are very deliberate to avoid a tremendous amount of complexity from applications to handle arbitrary IME behavior.  Even with a way to push the app to the side instead of app, you aren't goinmg to be happy with the result because the vast majority if apps wouldn't know how to deal with that.  Sometimes working within constraints is good.

Comment: Sure.  So there is a class of possible Activities missing from Android, of which the IME is one specialised case, and that is the class of Activities which are designed work simultaneously with the current Activity - call them collaborators or something.  As you say, it would make it very easy for people to write apps that would not play nicely.  Its a shame because it leaves such things only in the hands of you very busy developers who cant think of/do every potentially cool thing.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with a class of activities missing, but just that if the IME was allowed to push the app in any way it wanted than app developers would have a lot more work to correctly write an app that dealt with all of those possibilities.  This doesn't leave things in the hands of busy developers, it is a reasonable compromise that simplifies things for everyone.  In other words... I don't think what you want to do with your IME is reasonable.  There are lots of things you *can* to in an IME that are; take advantage of those.

Comment: I understand that, but there are other ways to approach it if you wanted to make this sort of behaviour generic.  Like off the top of my head, lets say you allowed a collaborating activity to take up a certain amount of space around _any_ edge(s) of the screen, with the underlying activity still visible & usable anywhere it wasn't covered.  In order to interact with the covered portions of the underlying activity, it could auto-scroll that activity such that it centred around anywhere you touched it, revealing previously covered areas.

Comment: _My actual keyboard idea_ is simply a vertical strip keyboard along each side of the screen, with the keys A-M down one side and the keys N-Z up the other.  Accuracy and prediction-wise, its better than a 2-d grid because each key only has two neighbours, and its in normal alphabetical order so wouldn't be hard to 'learn'.  I reckon you could bang away with two thumbs pretty quickly.

Comment: When you touch down on a key, a horizontal list of possible characters slides out.  if you slide your finger you can highlight one of those and then release to select.  For English, that might only be to capitalise a character, but for other languages (i.e. Japanese which uses 5 character groupings ) it could be a useful way to choose between related groups of characters where the entire alphabet is too large to fit on the screen at once.  Spacebar, numbers and symbols could be placed along bottom and/or top edges in a horizontal strip, leaving a large part of the screen still visible below.

Comment: Might not be _possible_, but I think its _reasonable_.  thoughts?

Comment: You can do a lot with an IME.  You aren't going to be able to make applications push their left and right edges away from your IME like that.  Take a look at a portrait screen.  Where in the *world* do you think apps are going to put their UI if they get in that situation?  Why don't you start playing with the IME stuff and see what you can do.

Comment: Also, we aren't talking about collaborating activities.  First, the IME isn't an activity.  Second, these are independent things.  They are only superficially collaborating in that the application is finding out that it has to resize and deal with it.  As I said, putting app developers in a situation where they need to design their UI so that they can work well with whatever an IME throws at it would just be a tremendous increase in trouble for them.  It is trivial to throw this kind of stuff at the app.  It is bad to make every app have to deal with it.  Anyway enough of this conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you could create a rectangle where ever you want and make bits of it transparent.  Not sure how to pass UI events to the activity below your keyboard though.

Anyway, there's a [softkeyboard sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html) that will probably be Quite Helpful.

As I see it there are two ways you might handle the UI Thing.
  - Pass events off to the underlying activity when they "should go through"... As your softkeyboard may have its own process, this could get a bit thorny.
  - Make your keyboard up of more than one rectangular region, such that the UI events pass through Naturally.  I'm not sure if that's even possible.  I'm still fairly new to Android development myself.

Comment: My understanding is that Activities are fullscreen and that the keyboard and a few other things like it are something other than Activities.  These 'something elses' are designed to work on top of Activities such that the area they dont obscure is usable.

Comment: HOWEVER- Do these 'something other than Activities' have to be a rectangle at the bottom of the screen?  Because you notice when the typical soft keyboard appears, it pushes text input boxes upwards so that they are visible in the top half of the screen that isnt covered by the keyboard.  If I dont want my keyboard parts to appear at the bottom, how does that interaction with the underlying input fields work?  Have the Android developers made assumptions about keyboard shape and placement that make non-default shape and placement impractical/impossible?